# order_with_respect_to() Child relationship

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to figure out how I can use:
    order_with_respect_to()
to order via a Child relationship

```
class Product(models.Model):
   name = models.CharField(max_length=100)

class Affiliate(models.Model):
   product = models.ForeignKey(Product)
   clicks = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

I want to be able to display the Products in order of the the number of affiliate clicks.

All the examples I have seen are ordering Child relationships via Parent attributes.

Perhaps there is a better way of doing this other than order_with_respect_to()

thanks,
Bryan

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Take a look at aggregates (http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/aggregation/). I think you can use them to help you with this problem.

Answer (score 0):

See `order_with_respect_to` documentation [here](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/options/#order-with-respect-to), updated since this question was posted.